# NSURLSession, multiple data tasks, completionHandler

Tags: nsurlsession, completionhandler

I would like to use `NSURLSession` and `dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler:` to download 4 different URLs into `NSData` objects. I know I can call:

```
[session dataTaskWithURL completionHandler:^(NSData* data, NSURLResponse* response, NSError* error) {
    // handler
}];
```

Once these are added to the session I know I can start them with `[task resume]`. Is there any way to tell the session to simply start all the tasks I have added to it?

But how can I get notified when all four of them are finished (with an error or otherwise)? Do I need to keep some sort of thread-safe dictionary around to keep track of the state of each task?

My purpose is that once these are downloaded, I need to start a timer so the same four URLs can be downloaded again sometime in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No,  There's no way to start multiple tasks at once.
2. Yes, you need to keep a dictionary to store the responses, using the data tasks as a key.  Perform all modifications and accesses on the main thread for safety.

You might also consider a dispatch group, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047252/how-to-aggregate-response-from-multiple-nsurlsessiondatatasks).